# Visual Studio Code - How to add multiple paths to python path?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am experimenting with Visual Studio Code and so far, it seems great (light, fast, etc).

I am trying to get one of my Python apps running that uses a virtual environment, but also uses libraries that are not in the site-package of my virtual environment.

I know that in `settings.json`, I can specify a `python.pythonPath` setting, which I have done and is pointing to a virtual environment.

I also know that I can add additional paths to `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`, where thus far I am adding the external libraries. The problem is, when I am debugging, it's failing because it's not finding the libraries specified in `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`.

Is there another setting that must be used for this?

Comment: Did you read this: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Python-Path-and-Version#python-version-used-for-debugging ?

Comment: @jbasko, yes, i think i read everything out there.  They all indicate only that the python.pythonPath takes a single value that points to the python interpreter.  In eclipse for example, you can add external source folders.  But not sure how to do that for vs code.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you've read. So you have `"pythonPath":"${config.python.pythonPath}",` in your launch.json?

Comment: I have it set to the path of my virtual environment's python interpreter in all the files (settings, launch and task.json).  What you are reading states that if it is in the settings.json, it will be picked up if the setting is as you state in launch.json.  That's fine, but not my issue.  My issue as adding multiple paths (paths to external libraries) to the python path.  Much like you can do in Eclipse and other editors.

Comment: what OS are you using?  If in Windows, activate your virtual environment in powershell and just type "code[enter]" once it's active.

Comment: Here is a super hacky workaround until it is actually solved, add this to the top of your first python file:
`import sys;
sys.path.append('/path/to/my/pylib')`

Comment: Mike, You got an answer below. Take a look and mark it as the answer if it works, or comment on it...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This worked for me:-

in your launch.json profile entry, specify a new entry called "env", and set PYTHONPATH yourself.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "request": "launch",
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ],
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "/path/a:path/b"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Does the forward slash work in windows as well? I'm running with corrected pythonpath (after restarting VSCode) and still get missing import.

Comment: It doesn't work until I change *semicolon* to *a colon*

Comment: Just place an .env file in your VS Code workspace containing: PYTHONPATH=/path/a:/path/b
See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file

Comment: Im confused, is it a colon or a semicolon to make it work?

Comment: What is the difference between the .env file and setting `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` in settings.json?

Comment: test `;` semilcolon works in 2023

Answer (score 59):

The Python Extension in VS Code has a setting for `python.envFile` which specifies the path to a file containing environment variable definitions (Refer to: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file). By default it is set to:

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```

So to add your external libraries to the path, create a file named *.env* in your workspace folder and add the below line to it if you are using Windows:

```
PYTHONPATH="C:\path\to\a;C:\path\to\b"
```

The advantage of specifying the path here is that both the auto-complete as well as debugging work with this one setting itself. You may need to close and re-open VS Code for the settings to take effect.

Comment: This still works in 2019. I add that if you are using pipenv, you have to set the path to the /User/.virtualenvs/{$projectname} in order to have the corrent environment with the installed libraries

Comment: Info: this worked for me with a VSCode attached to a running container;

If someone find this usefull: `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python"` & `.env` -> `PYTHONPATH="/usr/src/my-project/a;/usr/src/my-project/b"`

Comment: This is the best way.  `.env` files are commonly used in more applications (and languages) than VS Code.  The `.env` file can travel with the source code and still be recognized by other engines/IDEs, where the `settings.json` file is specific to VS Code.

Comment: Importing numpy failed for me after doing it this way

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you. This was frustrating me for a while.

Comment: How to add a relative path to ${workspaceFolder} to PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: Worked for me as well using a relative path rather than full path

Answer (score 15):

In 2022, the configuration is as file `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["C:/Program Files/obs-studio/data/obs-scripting/64bit"],
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "C:/Program Files/obs-studio/data/obs-scripting/64bit;${env:PYTHONPATH}",
        "PATH": "C:/Program Files/obs-studio/data/obs-scripting/64bit;${env:PATH}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be done in a .env file?

Comment: setting in .env doesn't work, but this worked for me(windows)

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com No, `${pathSeparator}` contains the path separator (`/` or ``\``), not `:` or `;`.

Comment: `settings.json` isn't necessarily in `.vscode`. To get the correct one, press Ctrl+Shift+P, type `settings.json` and select "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)". Also on Linux it's `"terminal.integrated.env.linux"`.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, **malbs** answer doesn't work for me until I change semicolon to a colon,[you can find it from ZhijiaCHEN's comments](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/832)

```
"env": { "PYTHONPATH": "/path/to/a:/path/to/b" }
```

Alternatively, I have a hack way to achieve the same:

```
# at the top of project app script:
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/a')
sys.path.append('/path/to/b')
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12085, I added the following to the `settings` portion of the workspace config file.  I'm using Linux.  For Windows, use `terminal.integrated.env.windows`.

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "addl-path-entry1:addl-path-entry2"
}
```

I also added an `.env` file as described by many posts/comments above.

Finally, I added the [PyLance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) extension per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64103291/11262633.

I also reloaded my workspace.

These two changes allowed me to run Python programs using the debugger and the Run menu.  AutoComplete is aware of the added path, and my VSCode linter (was the default linter `pylint`, now ``pylance```) now works.

Comment: This worked for me for OSX, using 
`"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "addl-path-entry1:addl-path-entry2"
}`

Answer (score 5):

You could add a .pth file to your virtualenv's site-packages directory.

This file should have an absotute path per line, for each module or package to be included in the PYTHONPATH.

https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path

Comment: I am using miniconda3, I tried all other solutions and this is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Only answer that fixed `ModuleNotFoundError` from `pytest` and `pylint` in Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

First, open `settings.json` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052/4284627):

> - Open the command palette (either with <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
> - Type *"open settings"*
> - You are presented with a few options, choose **Open User Settings (JSON)**
>
> *This image was taken in the [VS Code online editor](https://github.dev/)*
> [image: The dropdown list seen of the "open settings" options]

Next, add the following code to the file you just opened (right before the last `}`):

```json
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["/some/path"],
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["/some/path"],
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "/some/path;${env:PYTHONPATH}"
}
```

Replace the three occurrences of `/some/path` with the path that you're interested in. If you're interested in several paths, put them in different strings separated by `,` on the two first lines, and in the same string separated by a `;` on the `"PYTHONPATH"` line.

The code above is for Linux, if you're on Windows, replace `"terminal.integrated.env.linux"` with `"terminal.integrated.env.windows"`.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work through adding "python.analysis.extraPaths" when using Pylance and IntelliCode.

Comment: @MagnusO_O Pylance and IntelliCode both come with the default VSCode python extension

Comment: note that this setting is already mentioned in the question post as something the asker knew already

Answer (score 0):

bash escamotage (works with debugger AND autocomplete); need to install code command in PATH (vsc shell command: install...)

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# vscode python setup
#

function fvscode {
  # you just want one of this:
  export PYTHONPATH=<your python installation ../bin/python3>
  # you may want many of these:
  export PYTHONPATH=<your lib dir here>:$PYTHONPATH
  # launch vscode
  code 
}
alias vscode='fvscode'
```

the launch VSC by typing 'vscode'.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [environments doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments), the places the [extension looks for environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) include some defaults and also the setting value for `python.venvPath` in the workspace `settings`

eg: `"python.venvPath": "~/.virtualenvs"`

This allows you to find several (eg: virtualenvs) as mentioned:

> To select a specific environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter
>   command from the Command Palette