# Visual Studio Code Python import paths

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to automate or relocate a `launch.json` setting to the user settings so I do not have to edit the same line in each `launch.json`?

I have many Python modules in a directory outside of the Python Path and currently am having to edit each `launch.json` file to add the following line:

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "\\my\\custom\\path"}
```

I tried adding the following line to User Settings, but it did not work:

```
"python.envFile": "\\path\\to\\python\\env\\file"
```

where the `*.env` contains the following:

```
"PYTHONPATH": "\\my\\custom\\path"
```

VScode I can open any python file that import from a custom path, right click and run it through VScode - I assume VScode is calling the native Python interpreter and seeing the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Some Python environments (Spyder, PyCharm, etc) have a global setting for this, but I do not know how to accomplish this in VScode. Note VScode is consistent with PTVS; I have to edit the Search Paths for each Python solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: I believe the `.env` files take the format of `ENV=value`, so try it again with `PYTHONPATH=path`.

Comment: I tried that, following the current [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) following the [request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/544), but still cannot get it to work.

Comment: what if you add that custom path to the workspace settings, e.g., 
  `"python.pythonPath": "/opt/mypath/bin/python3",`

Comment: This was answered in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766220/894497