# How to set the root directory for Visual Studio Code Python Extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have no trouble running and debugging my project with VSCode Python Extension (`ms-python.python`), but since python sub-project root directory is not the whole project directory, all imports from my sources are underlined with red color and are listed in the `problems` and so `Go to definition` and some similar features don't work properly.
How can I tell the IDE where's the start point of my project:

```
Whole Project path:
  docs
  server
    entities
      user.py
      customer.py
  env
  viewer
  db
```

The `server` directory is where the imports path are started from:

```
from entities.user import User
```

Comment: Here is another approach from a PyCharm user to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76336712/16274938

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can create a `.env` file with:

```
PYTHONPATH=server
```

That will add your `server` folder to `PYTHONPATH` as needed.

(You may need to restart VSCode for it to take `PYTHONPATH` into account correctly.)

*Edited to clarify...*

Create a file named `.env` under the repo root e.g. `your_repo/.env`.

Also creating the file under the folder where your consuming code is, instead of under repo root, seems to work e.g. `your_repo/service/.env`.

For more details, see [documentation on environment variable definition files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file).

For me this worked without restarting VSC, perhaps this is a matter of newer VSC and extensions versions.

Comment: I had to restart VSC for it to work --spent a painful amount of time

Comment: Could you clarify? Where do I put the `.env` file, in the `.vscode` folder of my project or in the project root folder? And should its name literally just be `.env`, or should it be something like `python.env`?

Comment: @Ray We automatically pick up the file if it's named `.env` and it's at the top of your workspace. You can also manually specify the location your settings. Se the [docs on environment files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file) for details.

Comment: @BrettCannon: is there any way to check if this doesn't work? I am using VS Code on MacOS, with Python and Pyright extensions. I did restart VS Code after modifying .env file (PYTHONPATH=./apps:${PYTHONPATH}). 
Thanks.

Comment: @Averell you can simply run a script that prints out your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, e.g. `import os; print(os.environ("PYTHONPATH")`

Comment: That should be `print(os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH"))` i.e. you need the `.get`()

Comment: @BrettCannon does VSC have anything similar when doing wdl?  I checked your link, and it doesn't have anything at all about wdl/cromwell, so I'm guessing the answer is no

Comment: @GregDougherty I don't even know what wdl is, so I'm also going to say "no" 

Comment: @BrettCannon .wdl are files from the cromwell language from Broad

Comment: @GregDougherty https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=cromwell&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance suggests that no one has written an extension for Cromwell

Comment: After struggling with the `.env` file for hours I gave up and deleted the `.env` file. Renamed my source folder from `my_project/my_project` to `my_project/src`. And then the imports worked like magic without any kind of setting (that I'm aware of). @BrettCannon Is there some kind of magic going on here?

Comment: @CyberFly depends on what you mean by "imports worked like magic"; it's possible as we try to support `src/` where we can, but admittedly it isn't plumbed through everywhere.

Comment: @BrettCannon I found the source of the magic, the Pylance extension has an option to automatically look for common source folder names like src. The option is called `python.analysis.autoSearchPaths` and is active by default. Pylance also has an option to set the name of a source folder. This option is called `python.analysis.extraPaths`.

Comment: In my case, I was developing just the modules in VSCode. I had to set `PYTHONPATH=..` for the import statements to work in VSCode.  That's two dots to reference the root of the project as being one directory above the module.

Comment: no luck with this solution :(

Comment: Works for parent directories (PYTHONPATH=../../) when opening a workspace in a subfolder.

Answer (score 44):

If you are using the [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) extension you can set your source folder via the `python.analysis.extraPaths` option. It also looks for common source folder names like `src` by default, this option is called `python.analysis.autoSearchPaths`.

Go to File > Preferences > Settings, search for pythonpath. Under the Pylance options you should see **Extra Paths**, this is where you set your source folder.

Comment: Pylance is the only solution I have found to get the VSCode linter to recognize my additional search directories.  Thank you!

Comment: Easiest solution

Comment: Just remember to apply this modification in the **workspace's settings** to avoid all projects inherit this extra paths

Comment: i tried both of those settings, but after switching to pylance all of my imports are broken :(  `Unable to import 'my.library'pylint(import-error)`
i am using standard practice of `src` as root python dir.. pylance wants to keep including `src....` in import paths

Comment: Already setup but not working when you it has to find files in other folders inside the specified path :(

Answer (score 11):

The `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable which you can set to add additional directories where python will look for modules and packages.

If you need to set working directory for Visual Studio Code,

The better way is to customize `Settings.json` and `launch.json`, do like this:

```
// vi .vscode/Settings.json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python",
}
```

use `cwd` to Specifies the current working directory for the debugger, which is the base folder for any relative paths used in code. If omitted, defaults to `${workspaceFolder}` (the folder open in VS Code).

```
// vi .vscode/launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: your project name",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/server",
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want the server run properly without any IDE, just insert the `Root Drectory` in front of `PYTHONPATH` . Assume there is a  `server/run.py`:

```py
import sys
src_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, _src_path)
```

refer: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations

refer: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#python-articles

refer: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: I believe, `PYTHONPATH` here refers to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` that is fed to `python`, not VSCode's `python.pythonPath` setting. So technically setting the `PYTHONPATH` env variable is exactly what is needed to tell Python about the source roots.

Comment: Yes , but the question of "root directory" is expected to  'How can I tell the IDE where's the start point of my project'

Comment: The actual question was, if I'm correct, `all imports from my sources are underlined with red color ... go to definition don't work properly`.

AFAICT, all VSCode Python extension cares about is that the imported modules are importable, i.e. lie on the PYTHONPATH. At least, setting it fixed the "underline" and "go to definition" issues for me.

And definitely the statement `The PYTHONPATH is the path to Python interpreter` is wrong.

I don't know if there is anything else about "root directory" that I am unaware about, but most likely it has nothing to do with the issues of the TS.

Comment: @YuriShatrov Thanks and I have updated the statement `The PYTHONPATH is an environment variable which you can set to add additional directories where python will look for modules and packages.`  ,

Comment: small thing. workspaceRoot has been deprecated, use workspaceFolder instead https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_why-isnt-workspaceroot-documented

Comment: I can't find `python.pythonPath` in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference . I think it might have been renamed to `python.defaultInterpreterPath`?

Answer (score 2):

Setting PYTHONPATH is what makes it work, as noted above.  I use the following .env content so that it works for any project:

```
PYTHONPATH=${PROJ_DIR}:${PYTHONPATH}
```

This is essentially what PyCharm does when you check "Add Content Roots to PYTHONPATH" in your run/debug configuration.  It's a helpful setting, but it spoils you because your code fails outside PyCharm.

Or, if you run in terminal, first export:

```
export PYTHONPATH=...
```

Comment: wheere can i define export PYTHONPATH= in the launch.json/settings.json?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but these days I just step around the issue by setting the path in the code:


`current_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`
`sys.path.append(current_path)`
`project_dir = str(current_path)`

Answer (score 0):

I am writing another but more general answer in this thread since what I have seen there is some mis-understandings and confusions still going on. Because I am also coming from Pycharm and now using VSCode.

First thing sourcing a directory (e.g., in Pycharm it would be `source root`) in VSCode needs two different setups for both **Run** and **Debug** modes.

For Debug mode:

- Go to `Run -> Add Configuration -> Python file`. It will create a `launch.json file` (under `.vscode` folder). This config `launch.json` file will be only running during the debug time. Thus, do not expect this configuration will help you in case of executing your code during run-time.
- Inside of this file and under `"configurations"`, add these lines. Note that here `core` is an example directory. It can be either your `src` or `app` etc directory.

> "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/core", "env": {"PYTHONPATH":
> "${workspaceFolder}/core"},

- So, during debugging VSCode will pick up this `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and execute your code from this directory.

For Run-time mode (i.e., no debugging):

- Best and simple way to first install `Pylance` extension in your VSCode.
- Then, go to `Settings -> search for "Pylance"`. Go to `Workspace` tab (which means only for this project) and then scroll down to: `Python > Analysis: Extra Paths`.
- Finally, add an absolute path under `Add item`. E.g., for above core directory it looks like this: `/home/Sanchit/work/Project123/core`.
- During run-time, VSCode will pick up this extra import path. Thus, it will resolve your paths.

Final note that you should always execute your script from `Run -> Start Debugging (Debug mode)` and `Run -> Run with Debugging (Run mode)`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. My Python code's entry point (`main.py`) is under `./tools/` and there are multiple subfolders/packages in that directory. (Basically, `./tools` is my "src" folder.)

Meanwhile, my `pyproject.toml` and my `.venv` folder are in the repo/workspace root because I want easy access to a properly configured Python environment (with Poetry, Ruff, Mypy, and all) from everywhere in my repository.

I added the following to my `./.vscode/settings.json` (= Workspace settings) to get VSCode/Pylance to stop complaining about missing packages and incorrectly rewriting imports when refactoring/renaming modules:

```
{
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": ".venv/bin/python",
  "python.poetryPath": "~/.asdf/shims/poetry",
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["tools"],
}
```

(Note that I installed Poetry through [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) – adapt the path as necessary. However, I don't think you need Poetry at all to get imports to work correctly but I still added it for good measure & better support.)

PS: Interestingly, adding the above settings to the `settings` field of the `my-project.code-workspace` file did *not* work.