# unresolved import 'Blog' in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am getting a unresolved import "Blog" in visual studio code. It happened all of a sudden, I am using a venv through conda, I haven't changed anything with the venv, everything is still working, but it's really annoying to have it.
As I said, I haven't changed anything in the project that could potentially create this problem intentionally.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from Blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("blog/", include("Blog.urls")),
    path("index/", views.index.as_view(), name="index"),
    path("", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("signup/", views.SignUp.as_view(), name="SignUp"),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

Comment: Is there a module `Blog` in your project? Typically a module is named with lowercases, it is possible that the `PYTHON_PATH` is not set properly.

Comment: How do I set my PYTHON_PATH then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just a bug caused by a Visual Studio Code extension called "Visual Studio IntelliCode - Preview"

Answer (score 0):

If the `Blog` module is in a parent directory, then you might need a [relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057464/relative-importing-modules-from-parent-folder-subfolder):

```
from ...Blog import views
```

Or if it's in the same directory, you'll also need a relative import:

```
from .Blog import views
```

[More on relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

Another option is to set your [project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089498/how-to-set-the-root-directory-for-visual-studio-code-python-extension) in VS Code.

Comment: No, I am importing views.py from an app Blog

Comment: Ah, ok. Could you please provide your project folder structure with your question?

Comment: Ok, relative import may be the issue. Adjusted my answer with info on relative imports.

Comment: No, doing that just gives me an error. How it is right now it's working and it was working before, now it just gives me a "problem"

Comment: Which of the above options did you try, and what error did it give you then?

Comment: Looking at your structure again... am I seeing it wrong, or did all the `.py` files in `Blog` get moved into the `templates` folder? That would certainly cause your problem!