# How to proper setup python source root direcory in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, configuration, pycharm

I'm trying to setup a python project in Visual Studio Code. My problem is to create and use the `src` directory as source root (like it is working in pycharm). I have this directory structure:

```
project_name\
  src\
    __init__.py
    dta\
      __init__.py
      dtapy.py
    tests\
      __init__.py
      tet.py
```

My problem occurs e.g. with this code:

```
import dta.dtapy
print('ok')
```

I get the message:

> 

File ".../project_name/scr/tests/tet.py", line 1, in 
import dta.dtapy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dta'

I tried several tips like:

- add `.env`file with:
  `PYTHONPATH=src`
  to root directory
- setup `launch.json` with:
  `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",`

What is the proper way to setup this correctly in VS Code?

Comment: Same issue here. It's hard to believe there doesn't seem to be straightforward documentation to do this.

Answer (score 17):

Setting a source folder in VSCode requires some effort. Instead of adding a source folder via the PyCharm UI, you need to configure the PYTHONPATH for the editors' Python environment and the integrated terminal. You need to configure it twice, because not all Extensions use the editors' Python environment to run their commands.

The editors' Python environment is configured by the Python [environment variables file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file). By default this is found at **workspaceFolder/.env**

```
PYTHONPATH=./src
```

The integrated terminal is configured by the Workspace settings file: **.vscode/settings.json**

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  },
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  },
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  }
}
```

More info:

- [Setting Python source folders in VSCode](https://binx.io/blog/2020/03/05/setting-python-source-folders-vscode/)
- [Use of the PYTHONPATH variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable)

Comment: It doesn't work. Neither `.vscode/` nor `.env` exist in the project. I also created the `.vscode/settings.json` file manually and put the mentioned stuff without any result.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that Benyamin? Are you trying to run a python file from vscode, from command line, ..?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't use any `__init__.py` files and your project works fine in Visual Studio Code using this `project_name\.vscode\launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the addition of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. It's the same as would be set by marking that `src` directory as a Sources Root in PyCharm, though technically that's

```
 'PYTHONPATH': 'C:\\Users\\Cees\\PycharmProjects\\testimport;C:\\Users\\Cees\\PycharmProjects\\testimport\\src;C:\\Program '
               'Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
               '2020.2.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend;C:\\Program '
               'Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
               '2020.2.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
```

according to `pprint(dict(os.environ))`

Answer (score 0):

Using a `.env` file with relative paths **and** changing your current working might confuse things. I would just use the `.env` file. Also delete the `src/__init__.py` file as it's unnecessary. Finally, I would move your `tests/` directory up out of `src/` so it's next to it, otherwise it should probably be under `dta/` and then use relative imports.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! So here is the easiest way I found to set up this as a very loyal PyCharm user.

My usual project configuration is very similar to the one in question:

```
project_name\
  src\
    main.py
    controllers\
      endpoints.py
    tests\
      test.py
```

### Run and debug config file

VSCode uses a .json file to configure how it runs and debugs your Python project. This file is called `launch.json` and is stored in  `project/.vscode/`

The magic line here is the `cwd` property that allows to set a path for the main execution of the project. Here is the `launch.json` file that works for me:

```json
    {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
          {
             "name": "Python: FastAPI",
             "type": "python",
             "request": "launch",
             "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
             "module": "uvicorn",
             "args": [
                 "main:app"
             ],
             "jinja": true,
          }
       ]
    }
```

This will run and debug your project EVERY TIME as if `src` was the actual root, the *sources root*

Comment: there's no `.vscode/` anymore

Answer (score -3):

Not really an answer, but still...

Name that directory `project_name` instead of `src`.

Together with `__init__.py` inside that directory, create `__main__.py` file with your `main` function in it:

```
def main():
    # call your app from here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

That way you may start your app from the root directory of your project (first `project_name`) with:

```
$ python -m project_name
```

And your `launch.json` configuration for VS Code (click that gear icon in the Debug section) should be like:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "project_name",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```