# Unable to import from a own modul

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

this is my first question and I searched the whole internet for one day and couldn't find a solution.
Hopefully someone can help me here.

I have running Anaconda and Python 3.8.3 64-bit on Windows 10.

I want to import an own program modul from an other file in an other folder .

- foldera contains a testa.py file
- folderb contains a testb.py file. I want to import foldera.testa

The import does not work. Terminal says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
[VS Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUER3.png)

What I tryed:

- put the file: `__init__.py` and `.env`in every project folder.
- Reinstalling both programs and deleted temp files
- Looking folder .vscode into settings.json showed that the python.pythonPath is set correctly to python.exe
- Typed in python.exe sys.path.append('\\path\\to\\whatever')
  and os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '\\path\\to\\whatever'

Thank you in advance for the help

Best regards
Sepp

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please NEVER post text (as in code, error messages etc.) as images. Read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions. A well asked question is way more likely to receive answers that actually help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the root directory for Visual Studio Code Python Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089498/how-to-set-the-root-directory-for-visual-studio-code-python-extension)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking about? The title and image show a different issue.

Comment: As you are new, I'll explain a little more. My second comment means, that I flagged your question as duplicate, as I think it has been answered before. Please read this question and the answers carefully and try if this solves your problem.

Comment: @toydarian i tried it and wondered because in the settings.json file the filepath are written different. pythonPath \, envFile /
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"

Comment: @toydarian sadly that hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a project with the same folder structure as yours, like the following screenshot shows:

[image]

In launch.json, you should add

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
```

when testb.py looks for the module, this setting makes it first to search in the current workspace folder, and the code `sys.path.append("./")` let it turn to its parent directory, now testb.py is at the same level as foldera, so you can use `import foldera.testa` without any errors.