# Python ImportError and ValueError in VSCode/pytest

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pytest

This is what my project looks like (oversimplified):

```
root/
├── test/
|   └── test_code.py
└── code.py
```

Whenever I run **pytest** standing in root/ I get *ImportError : Attempted relative import with no known parent package.*

If I move `test_code.py` out to root/ everything works fine. But this is not an option since I have many modules and that is why I need to put ALL test modules inside a test-folder for organizing.

I am using VSCode and the weird thing is: **VSCode finds my imported functions inside test_code.py.**

`from ..code import func` - if I right-click on `func` VSCode jumps up to `code.py` outside of test-folder.

When I try to run `test_code.py` directly in VSCode I get *ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package.*

How can VSCode find my imported functions but cannot run them and pytest cannot run them either?

- I have tried adding `__init__.py` to make root/ a package.
- I have tried adding `.env` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089498/how-to-set-the-root-directory-for-visual-studio-code-python-extension).

## Solution

1. I moved `code.py`into src/ and added `__init__.py` files in each folder to let Python know that test/ and src/ are packages:

```
root/
├── test/
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── test_code.py
└── src/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── code.py
```

2. I had to use **absolute** imports in all files:
   `from folder.file import function`. Read about absolute vs. relative imports [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#syntax-of-import-statements). If you open your code in root - VSCode will now find your imports!

This is what test_code.py looks like:

`from src.code import func`

Finally, running **pytest** works! If you want to run `code.py` from **terminal** you have to run:
`$ python3 -m src.code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

1. I moved `code.py`into src/ and added `__init__.py` files in each folder to let Python know that test/ and src/ are packages:

```
root/
├── test/
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── test_code.py
└── src/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── code.py
```

2. I had to use **absolute** imports in all files:
   `from folder.file import function`. Read about absolute vs. relative imports [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#syntax-of-import-statements). If you open your code in root - VSCode will now find your imports!

This is what test_code.py looks like:

`from src.code import func`

Finally, running **pytest** works! If you want to run `code.py` from **terminal** you have to run:
`$ python3 -m src.code`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try like this:

- in `root`, create a directory `src`  and move code.py into it
- create an empty *__init__.py* file in both `test` and `src` directories
- in your test_code.py file, try replacing:

  - `from ..code import func`
  - with `from src.code import func`
- make sure `root` is the current working directory

Now, you should be able to run your script from VS code and running `pytest .` from your terminal should also work.

Comment: Thank you, I did exactly as you suggested. I had to import in this way for VSCode to find everything: from ..src.code import func.

Now when I run from VSCode or through pytest I get same error: ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package.

Comment: Additional comment: I tried to run: `python3 -m pytest` and get the same error.