# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError in python with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a basic manager of students' degrees for learning Python, also I'm coding in VS Code and with python 3.7.3 enviroment.

I have created a package named `clases` inside of which are `__init__.py` and `NotaParcial.py` files, inside `NotaParcial.py` is just one class named `NotaParcial` too.

The problem appears when I try to use the class from other package using the syntax `form clases.NotaParcial import *`

I have tried already put an `__init__.py` file in the package.

The error message is:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'clases'
>   File "C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Ingenieria\Semestre 3\Parcial
>   1\Modelamiento de software\Tareas\PySAcademico\prueba\prueba.py", line
>   1, in 
>       from clases.moduloNotaParcial import NotaParcial   File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py",
>   line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py",
>   line 96, in _run_module_code
>       mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)   File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py",
>   line 263, in run_path
>       pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)

I've tried to call the class from a file located in a superior path of the package and it works.
I've tried use Visual Studio 2017 Community to repeat the process and in that IDE, it works and the problem doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug main.py VSCode needs to know explicit library paths. This can be done by setting the environment ('env') variable in launch.json. First step is create a 'launch.json' inside the .vscode folder.

```
/
├── .vscode/
│   └── launch.json
├── mySubdir/
│   └── myLib.py
└── main.py
```

If main.py wants to import myLib.py as module, VSCode can only do this if mySubDir is part of the Python path.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/mySubdir${pathSeparator}${env:PYTHONPATH}"},
        }
    ]
}
```

*{workspaceFolder}* and *{pathSeparator}* are predefined variables which will be substituted by VSCode.

edit: I noticed '*{pathSeparator}*' doesn't work well in Linux, so there I use ':' instead.

This thread gives a more extensive explanation: [How to correctly set PYTHONPATH for Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

First things first, There is a guideline available which mentions about capitalizing [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

I would recommend using a styleguide. It makes coding weirdly enough much easier.

Back to your class. There are multiple ways of writing a module and I would love to give you two different examples. One of them is to write a module like class which is basically a folder. Everything in that folder belongs to that class. This keeps everything together and depending on your file structure organized as well.

Imagine having the following file structure

- someclass [folder]

  - __init__.py [file]
- run.py [folder]

Note that `someclass` doesnt contain any capital letters which is important for the import in the `run.py` file. More about that later. You might be wondering what is in the __init__.py.

```
class NotaParcial(object):
    ...
```

Note: The class name always starts with a capital letter. while coding it reminds you that you are working with a class object.

In order to import the `NotaParcial` class in our `run.py` we simple do:

```
from someclass import NotaParcial
```

The `someclass` after the `from` keyword represents the folder which you are importing from. the `NotaParcial` class is the class which is available in the `__init__.py`. The `__init__.py` initialized the folder its in as a module.

This works nice when working with setuptools if you create a package.

Now, lets imagine we have your situation, we would like to import a class from a file which is not named `__init__.py`. `__init__.py` is still required, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).

- someclass [folder]

  - __init__.py [file] [EMPTY]
  - super_duper_scraper.py [file]
- run.py [folder]

The `__init__.py` is empty which is enough for us, our example class moved to `super_duper_scraper.py`. In order to import the same class from the previous example you have to import it like this:

```
from someclass.super_duper_scraper import NotaParcial
```

When understanding this, you should be able to resolve your exception: `Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'clases'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need remove the `clases.` from the import statement.

just like that,

```
from NotaParcial import *
```