# Python Visual Studio Code Module not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pikepdf

Have installed Python 3.7.6 and am trying to write a code in Visual Studio Code

Using: `import pikepdf`

Gets me the error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pikepdf'`

However, I run "pip install pikepdf" and I get:

> Requirement already satisfied: pikepdf in c:\users\ME\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (1.8.2)
>   Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.0 in c:\users\ME\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pikepdf) (4.4.2)

My installation path for Python is:
`C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`

And trying to change something in the "Python: Python Path" gets me more errors.

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments or something similar?

Answer (score 8):

The issue was that Visual Studio Code comes with its own version of Python, while I had installed my own.

The issue was solved by changing the version VSC was running so it matched the one where the modules were being installed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can check which environment your VSCode is using. You can do that by inspecting your left-bottom corner, here:

[image: Visual Studio Code image.]

When you are running your code, you are using `python` or `python3.7`?

Comment: It says Python 3.8.0 64-bit (and nothing else), though it's weird because when I use CMD and ask python version, it returns 3.7.6

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also occur when debugging a Python script from Visual Studio Code. In case you want to import a local python file the debugger can't find it. A solution is to load the module by path:

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute(), '..', 'subdir', 'myFile.py'))
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('myFile', path)
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader('myFile', loader)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

# now use the module:
module.myMethod()
myClassInstance = module.myClass()
```

Now debugging works fine, with correctly loaded my module.

Comment: While I found this works, this answer is better:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code