# Python - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, importerror, init, python-module

I'm new in Python and I'm having the following error with this simple example:

This is my project structure:

```
python_project
.
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_custom_lib.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py
```

And this is the error when I execute the `src/main.py` file:

```
☁  python_project  python src/main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lib import my_custom_lib
ImportError: No module named lib
```

If I move the `main.py` file to the root and then I execute this file again, it works... But it is not working inside `src/` directory.

This is my `main.py`:

```
from lib import my_custom_lib

def do_something(message):
        my_custom_lib.show(message)

do_something('Hello World!')
```

*Note:* When I execute the same code from *Pycharm*, it is working fine, but not from my terminal.

Comment: May I ask why is lib, that is code, outside src?  You say it is custom, is it shared between projects?

Comment: Hi @progmatico in my real project I have the `/src` directory and in the same level `/tests`. The problem is when I execute a test, it's trying to import the code from `/src`.

Comment: If you put an empty `__init__.py` under python_project folder, and every subfoder, you should be able to import from everywhere inside the project_folder package.

Comment: If you have shared libs between projects, you can either use a virtualenv and install those dependencies in it or place the shared libs in folders side by side with the project folder and append the folders into the sys.path from iniside your package entry point.

Answer (score 33):

Your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is set to the parent directory of the executed script. So if the executed script is inside a directory `src`, it will never be able to find the sister directory `lib` because it isn't within the path. There's a few choices;

- Just move `lib/` into `src/` if it belongs to your code. If it's an external package, it should be pip installed.
- Have a top-level script outside of `src/` that imports and runs `src.main`. This will add the top-level directory to python path.
- In `src/main.py` modify `sys.path` to include the top-level directory. This is usually frowned upon.
- Invoke `src/main.py` as a module with `python -m src.main` which will add the top-level directory to the python path. Kind of annoying to type, plus you'll need to change all your imports.

Comment: Hi @MarkM, thank you! I understand. Maybe I'm doing wrong because I have a project with `my_project/src/` and `my_project/tests/` directories basically. The problem comes when I execute a test. Is there any other way to structure a project in Python to avoid this problem?

Comment: No need to restructure your project, having tests outside your source is good practice! If both `src` and `tests` have a `__init__.py`, and assuming you're writing traditional `unittest.TestCase` tests, you can leverage the standard unittest module to [discover](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) and run your tests with a simple `python -m unittest` from the top-level directory.

Comment: Who is Henrique Branco?

Comment: I guess someone who posted a (now deleted) reply/comment to this question. I'll remove that part of the answer.

Comment: more detailed explanation on how to set the PYTHONPATH: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 12):

If I may add to [MarkM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532947/9118298), if you wanted to keep your current directory structure and still make it work, you could add a *setup.py* in your root directory, where you can use [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) to create a package you could install.

If your file had something along the lines of:

```py
# setup.py

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
  name='foo',
  version=`1.0.0`,
  packages=find_packages(),
  entrypoints={
    'console_scripts': [
      'foo=src.main:main',
    ],
  },
)
```

And then you do `pip install [--user] -e path/to/directory` you'll get an "editable package" which will effectively a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the package in your development directory, so any changes you make will not require a reinstall (unless of course you rejig package structure or add/remove/edit entry points).

This does assume your `src/main.py` has a main function.

You'll also need `__init__.py` files in your "package" directories, even in Python 3, as otherwise Python assumes these are namespace packages (I won't go into detail) and the `find_packages()` call won't find them.

This will also allow your relative imports to work. Absolute imports will only work when invoking the script from your entry point, but not when calling the script directly in your development directory.

Comment: What is *"ejig"*? *"existing"*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The text before your edits was correct: "you rejig" vs "your ejig". Please look up the definition of the word "rejig".

Answer (score 7):

You should have your main.py script above all Python packages in your directory structure. Try to update your project to the following structure:

```
.
|__ main.py
|__ lib
|   |__ __init__.py
|   |__ your_custom_lib.py
|__ another_python_package
    |__ __init__.py
    |__ another_python_scripts
```

After that, `python main.py` in your project directory will work.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `from a import b` incorrectly. It should look like this:

```
import lib.my_custom_lib
```

The other method is used to import certain methods, functions, and classes from a module, not the module itself. To import a specific function from the *my_custom_lib* module, it would look like this:

```
from lib.my_custom_lib import foo
```

Comment: In the main.py I changed "from lib import my_custom_lib" for "import lib.my_custom_lib" but I'm still having the same error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'"

Comment: make sure that in your code you reference the function as `lib.my_custom_lib.show(message)`

Comment: this is my code right now, but I have the same problem:

`import lib.my_custom_lib

def do_something(message):
        lib.my_custom_lib.show(message)

do_something('Hello World!')`

Comment: When I execute the same code from Pycharm is working fine, but not from my terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a relative import instead:

`from ..lib import my_custom_lib`

Comment: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package :(

Comment: Try following this tutorial, It might help https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent

Answer (score 1):

In my case in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), the actual error was in line 1.

I didn't import the _typeshed module, but by default it was there, so delete that module if you found it in line 1.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

[MarkM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532947/866333) is still excellent; I'm using [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index) now. I attempted to disambiguate what he was saying about "current directory". In case my confusion was an intended feature, here is how I did it.

```
cd ~/pypath
tree
```

Output:

```
.
├── proga
│   └── script1.py
└── progb
    └── script1.py
```

The script *script1.py* is the same in both directories:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Where I run it *from* makes no difference. [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) prepends the directory containing the script I specify:

```
cd ~/pypath/proga
./script1.py
../progb/script1.py
```

Output:

```
['/home/vagrant/pypath/proga', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

['/home/vagrant/pypath/progb', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, importing with explicit paths works best in such situations. If you need to go up in the tree, use '..'. The plumbing is a bit cumbersome, but it always works.

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute(), '..', 'subdir', 'myFile.py'))
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('myFile', path)
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader('myFile', loader)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

# Now use the module:
module.myMethod()
myClassInstance = module.myClass()
```