# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError in a Python file

Tags: python, python-3.6, importerror

I have a small issue regarding importing a class from another python file.

Here is the file that I try to import. The **EvaluationDetect** is a class from the **evaluation_detect.py** file. The file evaluation_detect.py is located into path

```
from oculus_evaluation.oculus_evaluation.evaluation_detect import EvaluationDetect
```

And Pycharm IDE always shows me this error message.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oculus_evaluation.oculus_evaluation'; 'oculus_evaluation' is not a package
```

Please I do not understand where is the wrong in this case. There is not possible to import a class. This a legacy code and I do not understand.

Comment: Did you try any of the MANY questions here on SO on the subject? To name just a few: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532337/python-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598292/python-modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-import-module-from-imported-package/54613085

Comment: Do you really want `oculus_evaluation` in your module spec twice?

Comment: I saw some good results by writing  ```import sys
from os.path import dirname, abspath
d = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(d)```

on **__init__.py**