# moduleNotFoundError: No module named in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new into python and I copied a folder from someone to try.
I import a whole folder with subfolders into a workspace from visual studio code.

the subfolder named algorithm has an **init**.py file which imports all the sub files(for example a file named calculation)
In the main file I'm trying to run is:
import algorithm as alg

all functions are recognized inside visual studio code when using alg. but when I try to run it, it still saying that the module is not found?
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asFXi.png)

What did I forget?
thanks in advance

Comment: Need more info either as error screenshots or Error console.logs

Comment: Can you share your project structure?

Comment: There are about ten different standard directories where Python will look for imported modules.  If you put your module somewhere else, then you have to tell it exactly where to look.

Comment: Could be the PYTHONPATH, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

[Algorithm](https://pypi.org/project/algorithm/) is a module that need you to install manually.

**Open an integrated Terminal** and if you're using virtual environment, activating it then installing the module. About how to activate environment, please view [Python Environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). Run `pip install algorithm` to install:

[image]

Then the import error should be resolved. If `no module named algorithm` still exists, run `pip show algorithm` to get its location and check if you've installed the module in current selected interpreter.