# Not able to call functions from another file (reportMissingImports) in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am not able to call functions from another Python file named fetch_data. I am using VS Code.

Edit:
Now I am able to import the function from the solution given by Molly. But I am still receiving error in VS Code.
[image]

Comment: use .env file for your workspace. export PYTHONPATH= in that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am not able to figure it out exactly. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: How's your folder structure like? please post it for me to reproduce your question.

Comment: See this question. Restart vscode after making the change. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **Workspace** Settings.json, add

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    \path\to\folder\which\includes\fetch_data,
],
```

Then reload window, the error should go away.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Molly! Seems like I am able to import the function now. I am able to print the data from the imported function but VS code is still showing the fetch_data line as a error. I am updating the screenshot in my question.

Comment: @Shivam Tawari. What is the error content?

Comment: It's the same error from the first screenshot. 
Import "fetch_data" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
And still I am able to get the data from that fetch_data.py file.

Comment: Can you share the settings.json? cause I've created the same folder structure as yours and set Pylance as language Server, no such error shown.

Comment: This is my settings.json.
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\shiva\\Documents\\Stonk\\ml_app\\fetch_data.py"
    ],
}

Comment: Delete `fetch_data.py` in the path. Right click `ml_app` and copy its relative path is easier than pasting absolute path.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks a lot! Finally it's working as expected :)

Comment: Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 2):

In VSCode:

- set breakpoint before import
- in the debug window:

  - `import sys`
  - `sys.path[0]`
  - put `fetch_data.py` in the shown folder
- restart execution

In StackOverflow:

- give credits for any help
- learn about **editable installs**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions sir. Being a beginner I am still trying to learn. Currently the solution given by Molly, seems to be working. And I will surely learn about editable installs. Thanks again.