# How can I specify a relative PYTHONPATH for VS Code unit tests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, environment

We have a Python project that requires setting a `PYTHONPATH` relative to `${workspaceFolder}`. We set it by adding an `env` block to our launch configuration, and specifying PYTHONPATH.

Unfortunately, our unit tests are not working well through VS Code in this case. We need to specify the path for unit tests as well. We can create an `.env` file and add the PYTHONPATH there, but we can't use `${workspaceFolder}` there - it is not expanded. This leaves us with one option -specifying an absolute path in the `.env` file, which is not good (we can't add this file to git, for instance)

Is there any way to specify environment variables for tests in a way that expands ${workspaceFolder}? This is the kind of thing that PyCharm handles automatically without any issues, and it's quite frustrating.

Comment: at the top of the unit test file, use `os.getcwd()` and `__file__` and modify `sys.path` or use the calculated path to adjust the files you are trying to locate, without a demonstration setup it is hard to help

Comment: Can this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code