# Python module not found when calling from another

Tags: python

I have this project structure:

```
/project_name
    main.py
    ----- __init__.py
    ------ /modules
    -------- __init__.py
    -------- module1.py
    -------- module2.py
```

I've edited to add more information. After working and testing a lot of recomendations to solve the problem, nothing works.

**Enviroment**

- Windows
- Conda virtual enviroment project python 3.10
- VSCode

**Problem**

When running main.py from VScode

```
from modules.module1 import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

this error raise

```
from module1 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

**Modules**

*module1.py*

```
from module2 import *
```

*module2.py*

```
def test():
    print("just testing")
```

So the problem always occurs when from main.py i import a module that imports another module. The second module imported from the module that i have imported from main.py is not found.

Still looking for the solution

Comment: You're probably running/your script from the wrong directory. Are you running things from `project_name/`? Or did you set PYTHONPATH correctly? Or use an editable installation (`pip install -e .`)?

Comment: You can also use relative imports: `from .module1 import method1` in `module2.py`. But this won't really solve the problem when running things from the wrong directory.

Comment: As an aside, `src` should almost certainly not form part of your package name. You should configure your project to search packages *inside* `src/`, so that you can then write `import data.module1` instead. Using Poetry this is especially easy by adding a line `packages = [{include = "data", from = "src"}]` into your `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: `src` is acting as a package here. So probably you should run `module2.py` as:
`python -m src.modules.module2` (Should run the line at dir: /project_name)

Comment: So, you mean that src folder is useless, isn't it? just move data back 1 level and remove src folder?. Many thanks.

Comment: As my enviroment is Windows, Conda, VScode, i can't the solution. Many different proposed solutions. I keep trying...

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try to set PythonPath first. If you use vscode to develop, you could [set this PythonPath in setting.json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53653083/15073910)
2. if module1.py and module2.py are in the same directory, you could try to use relative import. Please pay attention to cycle import as well.

```
from .module1 import Module1
```

3. main.py had better to move into src directory.

Answer (score 0):

## run the file from project_name folder

If you run a file from inside a folder, python will be able to look local module from this folder. You need to call it at the root of the project.

```
user/projects/package_name$ python -m src/modules/module2.py
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pycharm working directory

If you use Pycharm, you can configure the run configuration working directory to the root of your project.

[image: configuration panel of pycharm]

Answer (score 0):

## Import your package in editable mode

Create a `pyproject.toml` file in the root of the project with this content:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "package_name"
version = "0.0.1"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
```

Your package need to follow this structure:

```
project_name/
└── src/
    └── package_name/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── example.py
```

To install it in your environment from the root of the project:

```
user/projects/package_name$ pip install -e .
```

By doing that, you won't have to worry about PYTHONPATH, workind directory, relative/absolute import. You just import and use your package using the intended path you created, Python will know how to look thanks of the `pip install` command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Finally i've solved it including this line before importing my file module:

```
sys.path.append("X:\\path\\root_folder\\")
```