# Pythonpath and work directory setting to load modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

assume we have the following working directory, which is a local git repository

```
---project
__init__.py
   ---folder1 
      __init__.py
      functions.py 
   ---folder2
      __init__.py
      project.py
```

I use Visual Studio Code with the working directory based in the folder project. Assume `project.py` loads functions from `functions.py` which is in folder 1

```py
import (some modules)
import folder1.functions
```

This throws a `ModuleNotFoundError`

If i work with Pycharm, it is possible to adjust the interpreter, such that the above error doesnt occure
For VS Code i added the current working directory, where python is looking for modules by adding the following

```py
import sys 

sys.append('.')
```

This solves locally my problem, but assume you work on a larger project with a lot of modules and subfolders, and  modules loading functions from other subfolder. That would imply that i have to add "import sys ..." , into every python file existing in the git repository. Is there any easier solution? Like an option of Pycharm for VS Code?

Comment: I tried a similar setup like yours and it worked without using `sys.append(".")`. Could you provide more informations like how you run the code and maybe link the git repo?

Comment: By the way, it should be `sys.path.append('.')` instead of `sys.append('.')`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a similar behavior to Pycharm, you can create a workspace, edit its config and add the missing paths to the PYTHONPATH environment variables.
For example in the file `your_project.code-workspace`, if you are on linux, add in the settings :

```xml
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${env:PYTHONPATH}:${workspaceFolder}/folder1:${workspaceFolder}/folder2"
        }
```

Useful answer: [How to correctly set PYTHONPATH for Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for the original problem. You can search **Execute In File Dir** in settings.

If you uncheck it, VSCode will VSCode will have the workspace as the root directory.

[image]

It seems that there's something wrong with this settings. I've [submitted it to the github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21414) as a bug.