# How to config python environment at vscode debugging?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug my python code with VS Code. Below is `launch.json` file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "python": "/home/usr_name/anaconda3/envs/ENV_NAME/bin/python",
        }
    ]
}
```

It works fine until it finds break point. As soon as it reaches breakpoint, it stops debugging with below message (last few lines).

```
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr_name/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.14.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 988, in trace_dispatch
    self.do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/home/usr_name/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.14.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 165, in do_wait_suspend
    self._args[0].do_wait_suspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr_name/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.14.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 2070, in do_wait_suspend
    keep_suspended = self._do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg, suspend_type, from_this_thread, frames_tracker)
  File "/home/usr_name/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.14.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 2093, in _do_wait_suspend
    self._activate_gui_if_needed()
  File "/home/usr_name/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.14.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1592, in _activate_gui_if_needed
    activate_function()
  File "/home/usr_name/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.14.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydev_ipython/matplotlibtools.py", line 138, in activate_pylab
    pylab.show._needmain = False
AttributeError: module 'pylab' has no attribute 'show'
```

But in my conda environment, `pylab.show` works totally fine.

I already set Interpreter to conda env but that seems not directing VS code to use it in debug. Somehow it's stick with `/home/usr_name/.vscode/extensions/ms-python`. How to make it debug with python conda environment?

**Edit**: I'm not using matplotlib or pylab in my code. It works okay even with debugging. The problem occurs only when it hits breakpoint.

Comment: From my side, the "show" comes from [matplotlib.pyplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBX7K.png), what about directly using the "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" to import, will the same issue still appears?

Comment: And for the environment configuration, please also try the settings.json file. Configure this: {
  "python.pythonPath": "/home/usr_name/anaconda3/envs/ENV_NAME/bin/python"
} You can take a look of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code

Comment: I updated the question. I'm not using matplolib and the problem happens whenever it hits breakpoint :( I tried to set python.pythonPath in settings.json but it says python.pythonPath is "Unknown Configuration Setting".

Comment: please also share a minimal sample code if possible.

Comment: I'm running code from https://github.com/microsoft/muzic/blob/main/getmusic/track_generation.py I just wanted to see how things are working internally so I tried to debug it with VS code. Everything is fine until it hits the breakpoint..

Comment: Hi, I checked the source code you share, but there even no pylab be used, which line you set the breakpoint?

Comment: Right! That's exactly my point. I set breakpoint at line 260 trying to see how MIDI is encoded line by line.