# Visual Studio Code keeps throwing an unresolved import error for two module imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, windows-7-x64

I keep receiving an "unresolved import" error for a series of modules that my project relies on.

I've tried implementing the recommendations offered in the following two articles:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file
[Visual Studio Code - How to add multiple paths to python path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471578/visual-studio-code-how-to-add-multiple-paths-to-python-path)

In particular, I created a ".env" file in my VS Code workspace; the file has the following contents:
"PYTHONPATH": "c:\pct\pct-primary-internet-website\wagtail-src\wagtail"

My application code is in "c:\pct" however the module that VS Code is unable to find is located in the following directory:
C:\PCT\pct-primary-internet-website\wagtail-src\wagtail

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wrote your `.env` file using JSON syntax versus the syntax the file expects. Try:

```
PYTHONPATH=c:\pct\pct-primary-internet-website\wagtail-src\wagtail
```