# Adding to PYTHONPATH in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythonpath

I'm trying to add the src folder to my `PYTHONPATH` i.E. do the same thing as `Mark directory as sources root` in PyCharm.

I've looked at the solutions to [Visual Studio Code - How to add multiple paths to python path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471578/visual-studio-code-how-to-add-multiple-paths-to-python-path) but the solutions shown there do not work for me.

I've set up my minimal example as follows shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

My understanding would be that having a .env file with `PYTHONPATH="./src;${PYTHONPATH}"` would add the src file to the path.

Nevertheless, when running the code runner or when running `python change_pyhton_path.py` src is not part of the PYTHONPATH and the direct import from src fails.

I do have setting `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"`.

In pyCharm on the other hand everything works as it should after hitting `Mark directory as source` on src.
[image]

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 3):

in your `settings.json` add:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "full python path here"
}
```

Comment: This did not solve my issue. The behavior remained unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get auto complete working from your source directory, you could add to the PYTHONPATH environment variable as you are doing. You can also go the "vscode native" route, as there is a configuration. Open your workspace settings and add the following line:

```json
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./src"]
```

> NOTE: Avoid setting this at the user level as each project differs in where the source code lives

Answer (score 0):

if you have problems with importing modules and you are using code-runner, try to add

**"code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true**

to your settings.json file

Comment: Can you include inline code span so the code is readable & verifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
"env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}" },
```

to your `launch.json` could solve the problem