# VS Code: Is there a way to read a csv file without needing specification of the full path?

Tags: python, csv, visual-studio-code, file-read, project-folder

I am trying to read data from a csv file (in the same folder as my main.py) but it seems that
Visual Studio Code doesn't understand the project folder or something of the sort

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ratings.csv'

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# read data with panda, only the columns that are needed
r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating']
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', sep=';', names=r_cols, usecols=[1, 2, 3], encoding="ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False, header=0)
```

Adding the full path of the file fixes the problem, and it also works if I add
`import os` with `os.chdir` in the beginning of the code.

But PyCharm doesn't need the above tweaks in order to run it. So my question remains, is there a VSCode setting that I am missing?

Comment: Since you are using a relative path, vscode and pycharm are running the code with different `cwd`. In all likelihood, vscode has a lunch configuration you can tweak to specify the `cwd`. To verify print the result of `os.getcwd()`

Comment: How are you running the script? I can think of 3 options in VSCode: green run button, debugging, or from the terminal in VS Code.

Comment: @JasonCook I usually press the run code button on the top right (it's not green for me, the packages could be interfering). Debugging also has the same issue. Running in terminal actually does work fine, but I would rather find an internal setting to fix this globally and permanently.

Comment: Does this answer you question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471578/visual-studio-code-how-to-add-multiple-paths-to-python-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people mentioned in the comments, we can set the debug path in VSCode, please add the following settings in "`launch.json`": (It will automatically go to the directory where the file is located before debugging the code)

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}",
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and I solved it by doing this:

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Pandas/sample.csv')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def infolder_file( filename ):
    afname = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    current_folder = os.path.dirname(afname)
    uf = os.path.join(current_folder, filename )
    return uf

print( infolder_file( 'anyfilename.txt' )  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constant for the directory at the top of your module that you then use with any files you need to access.

```
from pathlib import Path

DIRNAME = Path(__file__).parent

def func():
    fn = DIRNAME / 'file.suffix'
```