# Changing the python bin for a django debug session in vs code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have this in my launch.json

## launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "python": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to change the bin used so that it doesn't use the normal bin of ubuntu but a virtual env (from pipenv shell).

does anyone now any configurations that i have to change to get this?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration in the `launch.json` file can be used to specify the python interpreter path. `"python": "${command:python.interpreterPath}"`.

For more configuration information, you can refer to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python).

Comment: `"python": "/home/gmv/.local/share/virtualenvs",` so like this? or `"python": "/home/gusmadvol/.local/share/virtualenvs/NEWPROJECT-agfYmyxR"

Comment: You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471578/visual-studio-code-how-to-add-multiple-paths-to-python-path).