# How to get ms-python to recognize packages that were not installed directly with pip

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-server

I am using code-server which runs vscode in a web browser. It is served through a cluster running linux/ubuntu. The install includes many ros packages which are installed in /opt/ros/noetic/... in other words they are part of the Robot Operating System. They were not installed with Pip but with apt-get install xxx.

In this copy of vscode I have installed the ms-python extension and it works well. I see pop ups with helpful information on everything. Except libraries that were defined outside of pip.

I am not sure how to configure things so that ms-python sees all these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41668211) can help.

You can set `pythonpath` (where your package is) in the `setting.json` to get the package under the other directory.