# VSCode pylance doesn't IntelliSense for my local modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, pylance

I am trying to get IntelliSense to work for my local modules inside my projects `lib` folder.
I have the following project structure:

```
.Python
 |---> lib
 |     |---> __init__.py
 |     |---> gw_marker.py
 |     |---> gw_mumble_link.py
 |---> markermaker.py
```

I tried to add `./lib/` to the `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` property in VSCode which didn't work. As seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huj4o.png) it will not show any suggestions for the local module nor the documentation of the definitions.

Comment: Have you tried restarting VSCode?

Comment: Yes, multiple times no changes

Comment: What exactly are you adding to your extra paths? Are you doing this in a global settings file? A workspace settings file? Also, lots of suggestions here: [visual-studio-code-how-to-add-multiple-paths-to-python-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471578/visual-studio-code-how-to-add-multiple-paths-to-python-path) and of course (perhaps more importantly) be sure you are following the example from VSCode docs: [enable-intellisense-for-custom-package-locations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_enable-intellisense-for-custom-package-locations)

Comment: I edited the settings.json of vscode I tried using relative and absolute paths, nothing changed.

Comment: it worked with the env file, but for some reason intellisense doesn't work when the variable was passed through as a parameter. It works in the `def main()` but not in `def on_release(key, name, mumble, marker)`

Answer (score 0):

According to this case in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3324).

This is currently by design. currently, we do not add user types in auto import unless it is already used (doesn't need to be current file, but by some imports or other opened files). code action on the other hand, adds all user types. this was a decision to make sure we do not add hundreds of user types in completion list.