# How do I setup VS code autocomplete to work with Python's virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to work with virtual environments and it works fine but im getting squiggly lines everywhere even when the code runs perfectly.

I've tried to create a launch.json file by going into `Run and Debug > create a launch.json file` and this is what my launch.json looks right now.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "python":"${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "C:/Users/DC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe;C:/Users/DC/FlaskTut/Environments/flask_project_env/Scripts/python.exe"
            }
        }

    ]
```

I've tried replacing the semicolon with a colon and a comma, replaced the backslash with double forward slashes and even changed the order of paths but nothing is working.
Another important detail might be that I'm getting a yellow squiggly under `"${config.python.pythonPath}"`

Also, I had `"pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}"` intially but VS code automatically changes that to `"python":"${config.python.pythonPath}"`

Comment: ... what exactly do you think `PYTHONPATH` is? https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH because whatever you think it is, it's not that.

Comment: i followed this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41668211/22699864

Comment: you misunderstood what it was talking about.

Comment: could you explain it then?

Answer (score 0):

"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "C:/Users/DC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe;C:/Users/DC/FlaskTut/Environments/flask_project_env/Scripts/python.exe"
        }
    }

]
```

> Remove "python":"${config.python.pythonPath}" as its not needed.

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

*launch.json* is just a debugging configuration file.
You can add intellisense paths using the following settings in ***settings.json***.

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "PATH/HERE"
  ],
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "PATH/HERE"
  ],
```