VSCode Python auto import not prefixing src folder
We have a Python project with a src directory where all our main code lives and the PYTHONPATH is set at the parent folder of src, so not src itself. We want to use the auto import function, but it keeps omitting the src folder at the beginning.
We specifically use it when creating a class or variable that is not imported yet, Pylance detects it hasn't been imported yet, and the quick fix pop-up shows. Pylance correctly finds the wanted class or variable, but omits the src prefix.
What we want:
from src.foo.bar import Bar
But we got:
from foo.bar import Bar
when we use Bar()

pretty sure https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572824/11107541
